# Unity iOS, Audio sample provider buffer overflow

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, agora

I'm using the Agora SDK in Unity to use the Video Call.
It's fine on other platforms, but that error only occurs on iOS.
As that error occurs, the audio is lost.
The audio is broken, so moving to another scene won't fix it.!!
Is there a solution?

Agora SDK is 4.0.0.5

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.